# Is there a way to show the current size of Java's sessionCacheSize on commandline?

Tags: java, ssl, jvm

I want to analyze size of ssl.sessionCacheSize which is currently used by my Java Virtual Machine. This size can be set via the `javax.net.ssl.sessionCachSize` JVM setting. Is there a tool (like jmap) that shows the current sessionCacheSize a jvm is currently using?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Java Virtual Machine. `sessionCacheSize` is the property of `SSLSessionContext`. There may be several SSLSessionContexts in the application. Which one would you like to monitor?

Comment: The session cache size can be set via the javax.net.ssl.sessionCachSize JVM setting. Since that I thought that the JVM has some kind of an internal cache reserved for storing ssl session data. Am I wrong?

Comment: 1. It is possible to create multiple `SSLSessionContext` objects. 2. Each object can be configured individually, e.g. by calling [`setSessionCacheSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/SSLSessionContext.html#setSessionCacheSize(int)) method. 3. If not configured explicitly, the default session cache size is taken from `javax.net.ssl.sessionCachSize` system property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could view which ssl session cache size your jvm is using by dumping the heap using jmap and then examining `SSLSessionContextImpl` objects in that dump.

**Dumping the heap**

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=dump.hprof $PID
```

**Examining the `SSLSessionContextImpl` objects using Eclipse's MAT**

- Open the dump.hprof file
- Open the Histogram view
- Open the inspector view : Window -> show view -> Other -> Inspector (beneath Memory Analyzer Views)
- Filter for `sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionContextImpl`
- Right click -> List objects -> with outgoing references
- Select one of your object instances, you should be able to see the `cacheLimit` being used in the inspector's attributes tab